# Android Studio library import error

Tags: java, android

So i am working on my university project nowadays and needed to use addTextChangedListener method on it. There weren't any problem at first but when i implement TextWatcher() it has a red underscore says that "invalid method declaration". And also override methods got "annotations are not allowed here". I dont understand what causes this problem so if you can help me i appreciate a lot.

```
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.text.TextWatcher;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    EditText activityTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtActivity);
    EditText whereTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWhere);
    EditText whenTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWhen);
    EditText withTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWith);
    Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);

    mobileNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mobileNumber.setError(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            mobileNumber.setError(null);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forget to define: **mobileNumber**, this should be a textEdit. Your TextWatcher code has no problem.

Please also remove your unused import:

```
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimize imports by pressing `CTRL + ALT + O` together

Comment: it says unused imports not found when i drag my mouse on TextWatcher and delete related imports ?